# Return the longest subarray of repeating members C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm learning C# and trying to solve the following problem:
**Return the longest subarray of repeating members** e.g. if the array is {1,2,2,3,4,4,4} I should return {4,4,4}. I tried to do this but it returns the first subarray and not the longest. What I know about C# so far:

- Loops
- Conditionals
- Arrays

Any ideas ?

EDIT : My code so far
EDIT : Yes I do know something about multidemensional arrays

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sequence
{
class Sequence
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Console.Write("Enter size:");
        int size1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array1 = new int[size1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= size1-1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write ("Ënter Number:");
            array1[i]=Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        int bestLenght = 0;
        int bestStart = 0;
        int lenght = 0;
        int start=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size1 - 2; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && array1[i] == array1[i + 1])
            {
                start = 0;
                lenght = 2;
                if (bestLenght < lenght)
                {
                    bestLenght = lenght;
                    bestStart = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (i != 0 && lenght != 0 && array1[i] == array1[i - 1] && array1[i + 1]   ==              array1[i])
            {
                lenght++;
                if (bestLenght < lenght)
                {
                    bestLenght = lenght;
                    bestStart = start;
                }
            }
            else if (i != 0 && array1[i - 1] != array1[i] && array1[i] == array1[i + 1])
            {
                start = i;
                lenght = 2;
                if (bestLenght < lenght)
                {
                    bestLenght = lenght;
                    bestStart = start;
                }

            }
            else 
            {
                lenght = 0;
            }


        }
        Console.WriteLine(bestLenght);



    }
}
```

}

Cureently I'm trying just to return the lenght of the longest array

Comment: So please show some code what you tried so far

Comment: Dear Answerers, being a beginner, please avoid LINQ.

Comment: Do you know about multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: You wouldn't learn if we give you a solution. If you want us to point your error, show your code.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal But it would only be one line! :-)

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: I know, even i could have given him, but our motive should to increase his logic. Read dystroy comment.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I know that; that's why my comment closes with a `:-)`

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Good. That means we are on same side.

Comment: Can we have clarification, what is the correct answer for `{1,2,2,1,1,3,1,1,4,4,4}`

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev I've updated with my answer with why your code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The problem with your code is it doesn't deal with the edge case when the longest list is the last sublist

Change

```
Console.WriteLine(bestLenght);
```

To Read

```
if (lenght > bestLenght) {
  bestLenght=lenght;
  bestStart=start;
}
Console.WriteLine(bestLenght);
```

Alternatively

You can do this with a linq Agregate

```
var x= new[] {1,2,2,3,4,4,4};
var y=x.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(new List<int>(),new List<int>()),
(a,b) =>{
   if (a.Item2.Count()>0 && a.Item2[0] != b) {
     if (a.Item2.Count>a.Item1.Count()) {
       a=Tuple.Create(a.Item2,new List<int>());
     }
     a.Item2.Clear();
   }
   a.Item2.Add(b);
   return a;
},a=>(a.Item2.Count() > a.Item1.Count()) ? a.Item2 : a.Item1);
```

What this essentially does is iterate over the collection using a Tuple to store 2 lists, `Item1` represents the longest previous sequence, `Item2` represents the current sequence.

For each item, if the current sequence is not empty and the first item is different then we are in a new sublist so check the length of last sequence, if longer that previous max we replace previous max otherwise just clear the list.

The final part of the agregate checks which of the two lists are longer (as if the longests subcollection is the last the Item1 length check won't have happened.

This code could be turned into a generic function to handle any type as follows.

```
IEnumerable<T> LongestSublist<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) {
return source.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(new List<T>(),new List<T>()),
    (a,b) =>{
       if (a.Item2.Count()>0 && a.Item2[0] != b) {
         if (a.Item2.Count>a.Item1.Count()) {
           a=Tuple.Create(a.Item2,new List<T>());
         }
         a.Item2.Clear();
       }
       a.Item2.Add(b);
       return a;
    },a=>(a.Item2.Count() > a.Item1.Count()) ? a.Item2 : a.Item1);
```

or even as an extension function

```
public static IEnumerable<T> LongestSublist<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
return source.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(new List<T>(),new List<T>()),
    (a,b) =>{
       if (a.Item2.Count()>0 && a.Item2[0] != b) {
         if (a.Item2.Count>a.Item1.Count()) {
           a=Tuple.Create(a.Item2,new List<T>());
         }
         a.Item2.Clear();
       }
       a.Item2.Add(b);
       return a;
    },a=>(a.Item2.Count() > a.Item1.Count()) ? a.Item2 : a.Item1);
```

allowing you to do

var longest= new[] {1,2,2,3,4,4,4}.LongestSubList();

Comment: I learnt that way... Deep end.  People should learn Linq ASAP it can get rid of so many loops and nested ifs!

Comment: Right...Have to...share me if any useful link you felt. I know there lot of links..bt ur suggestion

Comment: @Peru Try [LinkPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) its a great place to start and you even get a nice simple IDE, I use this for composing most answers!

Answer (score 2):

A very iterative approach in words:

- Loop through each item in your array.
- If the current item is the same as the previous item, increment `currentSeriesLength` by 1.
- If not, then check it against `longestSeriesLength`.  If it is bigger then store the `current index` in `longestSeriesEnd` and the `current index - currentSeriesLength` in `longestSeriesStart`.
- Save the `currentSeriesLength` value in `longestSeriesLength`.
- Set your `currentSeriesLength` back to 1.
- Your longest series will be a the series between `longestSeriesStart` and `longestSeriesEnd`.

It will be a good exercise for you to translate that into code.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically have to do it checking whether previous number is the same as current one and increment a counter accordingly.

To be Precise  "Loop through the array, copying the values to a new array " And as it loops through copy only if the counter value is higher"

Hope this helps

Comment: Repeating numbers may or may not be next to each other

Comment: we are copying only the repeated numbers first time

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you can do:

1. Eeasiest is to

   - Find all occurrences of every integer in the list
   - Pick that one with maximum occurrences.
2. Use a `Linq`, like this:

   ```
   var list = new List<int>{1,2,2,3,4,4,4} ;   
   var result = list.GroupBy(r => r).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).First();
   ```

   a) Group by numbers (you will get al `1`s in one group, `2`s in other,... and so on

   b) Order **groups** by quantity of elements in each in *descending* order, so the `4` in our case will be the first one as the group of `4` has 3 elements (more then any other)

   c) Get first element (a list)

Comment: What if `list=new List<int>{1,2,2,1,1,3,1,1,4,4,4}`?

Comment: @BobVale: it groups by *numbers*, and doesn't care about a *order* of elements in the list.

Comment: OP says *REPEATING* members therefore order does matter, your code would return {1,1,1,1,1} and not {4,4,4}

Comment: @BobVale: undertood your point, but **I** think OP's means that what I answered. Just wrote the question in not so clear language.. I consider example he put on.

Comment: really, I must be masively misreading OP's code then because it appears to check for consecutive sequences....